# Argument is not assignable to parameter - typescript error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having an error with my typescript application that I'm building. I'm using Ionic/Angular and one of the errors I'm getting is:

> [20:12:30]  typescript: C:/xampp/htdocs/project x/anonymous-social/src/pages/activity/activity.ts, line: 59
>               Argument of type '(data: DataSnapshot) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: DataSnapshot) =>
>               boolean'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
>
> L58:  (snapshot) => {
>
> L59:    snapshot.forEach(data => {
>
> L60:        data.ref.update({'read': "true"})

I'm not really sure why I'm getting this to be honest. Maybe someone can explain.. The code it is referencing is:

```
if(checkStatus) {
  this.database.database.ref('/users/'+this.userData.uid+'/replied_to')
  .orderByChild('read')
  .equalTo("false").once("value",
  (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach(data => {
        data.ref.update({'read': "true"})
    });
  });
}
```

This is syntactically correct isn't it? What am I doing wrong? Any help would be great! Thank you

Comment: Hey Jane, can you also share the actual firebase data document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to return a boolean from your `forEach` callback function. In your case, since you don't want to cancel the iteration, return `false`. So something like:

```
snapshot.forEach(data => {
    data.ref.update({'read': "true"})
    return false // Add this
});
```

---

Much like the plain javascript `forEach` method, you can return a truthy value from the callback to stop the iteration. So the type for the callback function is actually:

```
(a: DataSnapshot) => boolean
```

You're giving a function that returns `void` instead, which is what typescript is complaining about. While your code should work perfectly fine at runtime (since `undefined` is falsy), it doesn't match the expected type so you get an typescript error.

From the [firebase documentation on `forEach`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach):

> function(non-null firebase.database.DataSnapshot)
>
> A function that will be called for each child DataSnapshot. *The
>   callback can return true to cancel further enumeration.*

Emphasis mine.